# PHP Messaging Thread System

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, max

I have a PHP messaging system which works as follows.

message_thread table
id(pk), user1_deleted, user2_deleted

messages
id, thread_id(fk), message, message_date, sender_id, receiver_id, sender_deleted, receiver_deleted

I am trying to get a list of threads with the last message by just querying the messages table using the following

```
$sql = "SELECT thread_id, msg, sender_id, receiver_id, MAX(message_date) AS msg_date FROM messages WHERE (sender_id = '$user_id' AND sender_deleted = 0) OR (receiver_id = '$user_id' AND receiver_deleted = 0) GROUP BY thread_id.
```

This works but does not show the last message. it only shows the first message.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: add an order by message_id desc and see if that works.

Comment: GROUP BY thread_id order by id desc.

Comment: I really hope values like `$user_id` are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because it doesn't look like you've done anything here to avoid serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thanks but this still does not show the last message, only the first one

Comment: I do escape my inputs. I sanitise them and use validation functions such as ctype_digit();

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT id, thread_id, msg, sender_id, receiver_id, msg_date 
    FROM messages
    WHERE (sender_id = '$user_id' AND sender_deleted = 0) OR (receiver_id = '$user_id' AND receiver_deleted = 0)
    ORDER BY msg_date DESC
) AS SQLi GROUP BY thread_id";
```

Thanks for all contributions.

Answer (score 1):

end your query with this to reverse the order

```
 ORDER BY message_date DESC
```

as for why there is only one result.. we gotta see what the actual script looks like.